# SiriKit Intents UI - How to use INImage?

Tags: ios, ios10, sirikit

In the Intents UI framework, how can we access the data contained in the INImage object (which is a property of INPerson)? In Apple's API, there are only methods to create an instance of INImage and no way to retrieve data such as the URL of the image. The INImage class seems pretty useless without any way to use it. Am I missing something here?